# From an action, get a post variable, output to page, then halt execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to grab a post variable in a action, output it to the screen, and then halt execution?

in asp.net I would do:

```
Response.Write (Request.Form["blah"]);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
puts params[:blah]
abort
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to suggestions already mentioned, you can raise exceptions:

```
raise params[:blah]
raise params.inspect
raise params.to_yaml
# ...and so on
```

In this case, you can even just do `raise` without specifying anything. Rails will by default print out all `params` as part of its exception message screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send it back to the browser (output to screen?) to debug, you can drop this line in your action.  The "return" will prevent a double render error.  But this will not halt execution of after_filter if you have one.

```
  render :text=> params[:blah] and return
```

Comment: If you are just doing this to debug something, I would recommend just tailing your application server logs.  All of the params will show up in the logs.