# Passing a value from JQuery to my model and updating the database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I got a list of `Students` in `Register` model, and a join table called `StudentRegisters`.

A `Register` has many students, and a `Student` can belong to many `Registers`.

Originally I wanted to be able to mark students present/absent in the `register/1` or `register#show` etc, however instead I created a new page called `registration`, which is accessed by going to `register/1/registration` for example, and looks like this in the `register controller`:

```
def registration
  @studentregister = StudentRegister.find_all_by_register_id(params[:id])
end
```

Here's a screenshot of what the page looks like:

[image]

What the plan is, is that a student swipes their card, this gets read in the text field, the value is then looked up in the `Student` table i.e. `Student.find_by_card_id', and if the student exists and is present in the current table, check the`present`checkbox and display the current time in the`Time of Arrival`field, and finally save both changed attributes in the`StudentRegister` model, so that their attendance is saved. If the user is not existent then nothing happens, or if the student exists in the DB but not in the current table, maybe display a message, or just ignore it.

[image]

I've played around a lot with getting the table to be displayed and updated, and currently every row is a form in and of itself and has a hidden submit button attached to it, which gets activated with the checkbox's `onClick` function.

Have a look for yourselves:

```
<table border="1">
  <%= text_field_tag 'Card_ID',nil,  :autofocus => true %>
      <tr><td>Present</td>
        <td>University ID</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Time of Arrival</td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
   <% @studentregister.each do |t| %>
<%= simple_form_for t do |streg| %>
      <td><%= streg.check_box :present, :onChange => "submit()", :class => 'student_present'%>
        <%= streg.submit :style => 'display: none' %></td>
            <td><%= content_tag :span, Student.find(t.student_id).university_id, :id => "#{t.student_id}"%></td>
            <td><%= streg.label Student.find(t.student_id).first_name %></td>
            <td><%= streg.label Student.find(t.student_id).last_name %></td>
            <td><%= content_tag :span, t.time_of_arrival, :id => "toa_#{t.student.id}" %>     </td>
             </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

I also played around with getting the data displayed, so instead of using Simple_Form's `label` method, I used `content_tag` in order to give each row an ID (Thanks to a previous answered question). Not sure if that's the right way, but my source code looks like this:

```
<table border="1">
  <input autofocus="autofocus" id="Card_ID" name="Card_ID" type="text" />
      <tr><td>Present</td>
        <td>University ID</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Time of Arrival</td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/student_registers/14" class="simple_form edit_student_register" id="edit_student_register_14" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">    
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
 <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="c8B0JGs4ZLVILa4a4r4PJJrD/zFcLCDhTLscBKHbFeE=" /></div>
      <td><input name="student_register[present]" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input class="student_present" id="student_register_present" name="student_register[present]" onChange="submit()" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        <input name="commit" style="display: none" type="submit" value="Update Student register" /></td>
            <td><span id="3">w122341434</span></td>
            <td><label class="string optional control-label" for="student_register_Michael">Michael</label></td>
            <td><label class="string optional control-label" for="student_register_Jones">Jones</label></td>
            <td><span id="toa_3"></span> </td>
             </tr></form>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/student_registers/15" class="simple_form edit_student_register" id="edit_student_register_15" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">  
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="c8B0JGs4ZLVILa4a4r4PJJrD/zFcLCDhTLscBKHbFeE=" /></div>
      <td><input name="student_register[present]" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input class="student_present" id="student_register_present" name="student_register[present]" onChange="submit()" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        <input name="commit" style="display: none" type="submit" value="Update Student register" /></td>
            <td><span id="7">w678941512</span></td>
            <td><label class="string optional control-label" for="student_register_Stewie">Stewie</label></td>
            <td><label class="string optional control-label" for="student_register_Lee">Lee</label></td>
            <td><span id="toa_7"></span> </td>
```

I also created some JQuery in order to test out how it would work, but whenever I get a checkbox to be checked it doesn't submit the form, and whenever I get a time to be saved in the `Time of Arrival` field, and then submit the form, it doesn't store that time. Why is that?

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("input[name=Card_ID]").keydown(function(e) {
            var id;
            if (e.which === 13) {
            id = this.value;
            alert("That"); //Just to see that it works
            $('#toa_'+id).text('2001-01-01 14:13:46 UTC'); 
//Sets the time for the row which as the toa_id that was entered in the checkbox 
(Remember this is just a test to see how it works, in reality the Student ID should be   checked, not the form ID)
            $('form#edit_student_register_14 input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
            alert("This");
        $('form#edit_student_register_14').submit();
        }
    })});
```

Comment: You should separate the problems happening at client side from the server side and attack them separately. For client side, check the 'developer tools' or firebird to find out the form parameters submitted. From your Rails server log, find out whether the server got the request. For debugging purpose, I generally replace save with save! so that I can keep track of which validations failed.

Comment: Is there any step-by-step instructions on what you mean? Not very familiar with the debugger for the web browser

Comment: This should help you:  http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/15/debugging-javascript-with-chrome.aspx  http://www.sagarganatra.com/2011/05/javascript-debugging-with-chrome.html

Comment: Besides the debugging, I'm more interested in writing to the database via AJAX and JQuery. Any instructions on that?

Comment: Javascript is getting executed on client's browser and your web application is getting executed on the web server, which most probably is running the database server. So, your javascript should make an HTTP request (POST or PUT request) to the web server, which should execute a controller action on your rails app where you should put the code to write into the database.

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/ this should help.

Answer (score 0):

First think you should do, is to make sure your form data are correctly landing in your server page, not in a wrong URL, and this could be done by outputting the received request in your server side to the web page. once this is done then you can manage your form data in your server side and continue the database operations process.

```
puts params[:blah]
abort
```

Taken from : [From an action, get a post variable, output to page, then halt execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775128/from-an-action-get-a-post-variable-output-to-page-then-halt-execution)

Once this is done, then you should be able to do the processing in your server side and keep tracking using the same way.

This is one way to debug your network queries using Chrome browser, you can see the list of your outgoing queries, you can save the networks traffic by clicking `Preserve Log upon Navigation` 
[image: Once clicked this button becomes RED]
:

[Chrome Network Debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network)

I hope this helps.